# parent of clicked item get the child

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-traversing

I am trying to travers up the tree and then down again but I do not seem to be able to combine the parent method and a regular selector.

here is what I am trying, I need to get the parent to establish the element that is being clicked and then traverse down again to the selector (#info div.tab)

```
$( $(this).parent() > '#info div.tab').addClass('hide-tab');
```

Comment: You should show us your relevant html code as i suspect it is not valid

Comment: The `>` only gets used as a selector when it is inside a string.  In your code, it is being interpreted as the "greater than" operator and converting `$(this).parent()` to a string to do a comparison.  Your code evaluates to `$(true).addClass('hide-tab');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$(this).parent().children('#info div.tab').addClass('hide-tab');
```

But as IDs must be unique on context page, should be:

```
$('#info div.tab').addClass('hide-tab');
```